# Measure-Object on series of numbers doesn't produce anything but count

Tags: powershell

I have file that is of the form:
`[0-9]+ [a-zA-z ,]+`

```
3671184 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
3195403 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Transfered zip file failed validation
1118052 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: BIP job failed
190220 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
163155 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.xdo.servlet.CreateException
136588 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Atleast One of the Child requests ended in error or Warning
85080 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Could not update entity indexing state for entity with uuid: '{.uuid}' in meta model version with uuid '{.uuid}': method [PUT], host
75707 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Failure during Schedule Item Import job..
69138 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Spawned job for request {.request_id} produced the business error exit code: BIZ_ERROR
57302 Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Returning a business error. Do not re-try.
```

Basically, a `uniq -c` count summary of occurrences of some text. I am trying to get the stddev of the counts using `Measure-Object` but what I am getting is just the count. I suspect it looks at these as a non-numeric type or non-array type and doesn't know what to do except count. I am not sure which it is

```
 gc ./uniq.txt |  %{$_.split(" ")[0]} | select -First 10
1333235
597499
168347
71893
50226
37268
31637
27127
26045
15540

gc ./uniq.txt | %{$_.split(" ")[0]} | Measure-Object   

Count             : 895
Average           : 
Sum               : 
Maximum           : 
Minimum           : 
StandardDeviation : 
Property          :
```

How do I get `MeasureObject` to fill in these details

Comment: `Measure-Object -AllStats` probably is what you're looking for. Unless you want something more specific like `-Sum` or `-StandardDeviation` ?

Comment: What is the format of uniq.txt? Eg how is it laid out?

Comment: the format of the file is the first line. You have `[0-9]+ [a-zA-z ,]+`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - That almost turned out to be the right answer. I just assumed it would do that naturally. It needs to be converted to int[]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, this finally gets the answer (you have to convert to int):

```
gc ./uniq.txt | select -First 10 | %{([int]$_.split(" ")[0])} | Measure-Object -AllStats

Count             : 10
Average           : 876182.9
Sum               : 8761829
Maximum           : 3671184
Minimum           : 57302
StandardDeviation : 1388994.88236442
Property          :
```